# roll widget out of the screen in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

i want to roll this container out of the screen, so that it animates upwards, and go out within 2-3 seconds. i am using this page as a splash screen.
my code for the container, which is wrapped by the align widget is as follows:

```
Scaffold(
   // backgroundColor: Colors.black,
    body: Align(
      alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
      child: Transform.scale(
        scale: 1.5,
        child: Container(
          height: 400,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.deepOrange, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(200)),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `SlideTransition` widget to animate the position of the Container:

```
Animation<Offset> animation;
AnimationController animationController;

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  animationController = AnimationController(
    vsync: this,
    duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
  );

  animation = Tween<Offset>(begin: Offset.zero, end: Offset(0, -1.5)) //negative to go upwards
      .animate(animationController);
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: Stack(
      children: [
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
          child: SlideTransition(
            position: animation,
            child: Transform.scale(
              scale: 1.5,
              child: Container(
                height: 400,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.deepOrange,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(200),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Positioned(
          bottom: 0,
          left: 0,
          right: 0,
          child: RaisedButton(
            child: Text('Animate'),
            onPressed: () {        //the button that trigger the animation
              if (animation.status == AnimationStatus.completed) {
                animationController.reverse();
              } else if (animation.status == AnimationStatus.dismissed) {
                animationController.forward();
              }
            },
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

In the example I showed a button triggering the animation, but you can do that in `initState`.

And you need to add the `SingleTickerProviderStateMixin` mixin for one animation or `TickerProviderStateMixin` for 2 or more:

```
class _YourScreenState extends State<YourScreen> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
```

Comment: thank you, it worked. one addition i would like to make in your code is we need to add the mixins as with TickerProviderStateMixin to recognize the vsync. :) thank you once again.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this nicely with the popular [Spring package](https://pub.dev/packages/spring).

Example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:spring/spring.dart';

class SpringExample extends StatelessWidget {
  
  // For the rotation animation to loop.
  final SpringController springController =
      SpringController(initialAnim: Motion.loop);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       return Spring.scale(
           start: 1,
           end: 1.5,
           animDuration: const Duration(seconds: 3),
           child: Spring.slide(
             slideType: SlideType.slide_out_top,
             animDuration: const Duration(seconds: 3),
             child: Spring.rotate(
               springController: springController,
               child: Container(
                 height: 400,
                 decoration: BoxDecoration(
                     color: Colors.deepOrange,
                     borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(200)),
               ),
             ),
           ));
  }
}
```